# moment.js formats incorrect year after adding 3 days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In javascript I get the current moment, and add 3 days to it. Why is the year being formatted as 2019 when adding 3 days is still 2018?

This fails when adding from the range of 2days 11hours through 3days 10hours. But works ok if outside this range.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var targ = moment();
    console.log(targ.format('GGGG-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z'));
    targ.add(3, 'days');
    console.log(targ.format('GGGG-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Console.logs show the following:

2018-12-28 14:39:38 -07:00

2019-12-31 14:39:38 -07:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GGGG` is the year of the ISO week and not the actual year:

[moment.js: Week year, week, and weekday tokens](https://momentjs.com/docs/#week-year-week-and-weekday-tokens)

> GGGG: ISO 4 digit week year

[Wikipedia: ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

> [...] The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the Gregorian year's first Thursday in it. [...]
>
> [...] If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, it is part of week 53 of the previous year. If it is on a Saturday, it is part of the last week of the previous year which is numbered 52 in a common year and 53 in a leap year. If it is on a Sunday, it is part of week 52 of the previous year. [...]
>
> [...] If 31 December is on a Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday, it is in week 01 of the next year. If it is on a Thursday, it is in week 53 of the year just ending; if on a Friday it is in week 52 (or 53 if the year just ending is a leap year); if on a Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 of the year just ending. [...]

So the last days of the year can belong to the first ISO week of the next year.

You are looking for `YYYY`

```
var targ = moment();
console.log(targ.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z'));
targ.add(3, 'days');
console.log(targ.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z'));
```